# Como executar um código javascript a partir do url do site

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web, html

Olá, tudo bom? Eu queria saber se alguém consegue me ajudar numa coisa no meu site de séries.

Ele não tem páginas, ou postagens, ou seja: tudo é feito a partir da página inicial.

Para abrir uma série, eu uso o código:

```
Abrir_Serie('exemplocode');
```

E o que queria fazer é tipo isso:

http://meusite.com/Abrir_Serie('exemplocode');

e automaticamente o código depois da url seria executado...

Mas não sei como fazer isso

Comment: Queres uma maneira de correr código passado no URL? Por exemplo: `http://meusite.com/Abrir_Serie('alert("foo");');`? Isso é perigoso em termos de segurança. Em que situação pensas/precisas de usar essa técnica?

Comment: Se você permitir a inserção de script pela URL, alguém poderá forçar teu site a executar scripts com outras finalidades(XSS). Porem, é difícil esse tipo de "brecha" ter alguma utilidade para quem estiver tentante atacar teu site, já que o script não vai fazer parte de um conteúdo da página, e não será exibido para outros usuários.

Comment: Mas você não precisa aceitar e executar scripts da URL, basta pegar apenas o parâmetro que você pretende utilizar nessa função "Abrir_serie". Ex:  meusite.com?serie=exemplocode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bem, você pode usar hashs na sua url, que seriam dados após o # da url.

Se a sua url for por exemplo http://meusite.com.br/home#serie/teste , você pode pegar o valor teste para usar na sua função da seguinte forma:

```
if(location.hash.search("serie") > -1){
    var serie = location.hash.split("#serie/")[1];
    Abrir_Serie(serie); //valor da variavel serie vai ser igual a teste
}
```

Dessa forma o seu site não estaria vulnerável a injeção de script maliciosos.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Era isso mesmo que eu queria!